# PHP $_FILE Temp Location open_basedir Conflict PHP-FPM/Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I have a script for uploading files to my site. It works great but now I'm wanting to extract meta data from video files using the [ffmpeg/ffprobe library](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg). My code:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
            $requestAr = requestCheck(['title', 'description']);
            $assetName = randomString(11);
            $assetSalt = randomString(3);

            $bucket = "videos";
            $fileTmpPath = $_FILES['qqfile']['tmp_name'];
            $filenameOrig = $_FILES['qqfile']['name'];
            $fileExtension = pathinfo($filenameOrig, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $assetFilename = $assetName . "_$assetSalt.$fileExtension";

            $trustedExtensions = ['webm', 'mp4', 'ogg'];
            if(array_search($fileExtension, $trustedExtensions) !== false) {
                $ffprobe = FFMpeg\FFProbe::create([
                    'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/bin/ffprobe'
                ]);
                $fileInfo = $ffprobe
                    ->format($fileTmpPath) // extracts file informations
                    ->get('duration');             // returns the duration property
                print_r($fileInfo);
            }
}
```

I wind up with this error:

```
file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/bin/ffprobe) is not within the allowed path(s): <lists all the directories in the open_basedir variable>
```

I have passed the ffmpeg library the absolute path to ffprobe so it knows where it is. I was searching around and some people were saying this is because the lib can't access the tmp directory with the uploaded file. In either case, I've been trying to disable `open_basedir` or at least add the paths I need to it to get this to work.

I tried setting `open_basedir` to none in my `php.ini` but it didn't work. When I view `phpinfo()`, it still lists a bunch of paths for that setting. I tried to grep where `open_basedir` exists on the server. Indeed, it's the `php.ini` files and I shouldn't need to modify any other than the one reported in `phpinfo()`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. For some reason, grep wasn't returning all files with the `basedir` string. I had to edit the php-fpm file for the specific site: `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/web8.conf` and append the paths:

`/usr/bin/ffmpeg:/usr/bin/ffprobe`

to the `php_admin_value[open_basedir]` directive. Then `systemctl reload php7.0-fpm.service` and done.